# Question about basic predator prey modeling exercise

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

### The Question

> Consider a predator-prey population consisting of foxes and rabbits.
> Without rabbits to eat, only $70$% of the foxes would survive each
> month, while the fox population grows by $50$% of the rabbit
> population each month due to the available food supply they represent.
> In the absence of any foxes, the rabbit population would increase by
> $20$% each month. The transition matrix $\mathbf{A}$ for this
> situation is given. The constant $r > 0$ is the capture rate
> representing the average number of rabbits consumed monthly by foxes.
> If $r = 0.12$, show that in the long term the populations of foxes and
> rabbits are stable, with $5$ foxes for each $3$ rabbits.
>
> $$ \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.7 & 0.5 \\ -r & 1.2 \end{bmatrix}. $$

### My Understanding

In the following problem, they say $20$% increase in rabbit population formulates to $1.2R_k$, however, $70$% increase in the fox population formulates to $0.7F_k$. Shouldn't the $20$% increase in rabbit population formulate to $0.2R_k$?

Comment: I don't see 40% anywhere in the problem. The transition matrix correctly represents how many foxes and rabbits there will be in the next month. foxes will be 0.7*current foxes+0.5*current rabbits. rabbits will be -r *current foxes +1.2 * current rabbits.

Comment: I edited my question, it was a typo and should be 70% not 40%.

Comment: @JohnL I don't understand why it is 1.2*current rabbits and not 0.2*current rabbits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that 'only 70% of the foxes would survive' indicates not a 70% increase of the fox population, but rather a 30% decrease! This will explain why it is $0.7F_{k}$ and not $1.7F_{k}$.

The rabbit population increase is in fact an increase as it is written and so should stay as $1.2R_{k}$.

Comment: ah, makes sense. Thanks.